# How to find official Transact-SQL syntax reference?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax

I'm trying to find T-SQL syntax reference and after about an hour of googling I've been unable to come up with anything useful. I don't remember having had any trouble like such with MySQL, PostgreSQL, PL/SQL...

I want to answer basic questions like:

- Which syntax do I use for strings? (like: can I use "double quotes", 'single-quotes'; which escape sequences there are?)
- Which syntax do I use for numbers?
- Which syntax do I use for table and column names?

What I've managed to find:

- [Syntax for comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comment-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [List of reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

I'm sure that what I'm looking for must be there on this same Microsoft site.. but can't find it.

Comment: [documentation for constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [database identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15) - aka regular identifiers.

Comment: Splendid, that's exactly what I was looking for. I would accept this as an answer.

Comment: Interesting to see down- and close-votes on the question. Care to explain what's wrong with my way of asking this question in StackOverflow?

Comment: Don't take it personally. I also find the upvotes mystifying as well.

Comment: FWIW, using <my favorite search engine> to search for `t sql data type precedence` or `t sql string_agg` tends to produce quite fruitful results and is generally less frustrating than trying to navigate through a website brought to you by the people who blessed the world with [PowersHell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/).

Comment: To those, who're casting close votes. A related post in meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385479/when-is-a-resource-request-on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation for [constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [database identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15) - aka regular identifiers.

Comment: Thanks. Navigating the Microsoft documentation has been really confusing to me.